Excel Pivot Tables Analyzer Refresh Problem
I have a pivot table. I also have a Date Filter and an analyzer (for a specific column). Every time i change a date, i expect the analyzer to change too, according to the dates selected but it does not! I have to right click and press Refresh to update. How can the analyzer be automatically updated every time i change a date in the Date Filter?
There is nothing special to do here. Just added Date Filter and an Analyzer. They both connected to the Pivot Table. Should update but it does not!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Maybe this will point you in the right direction: https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/refresh-pivot-tables-automatically/
